# Get Prices from html page

Tags: java, html

Hello i want to understand how to get a value specific all the prices from here example http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_nkw=iphone+5&_frs=1
and return the values so i can lets say add them into database along with the product name.

```
String weburl = "http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_nkw=iphone+5&_frs=1";
            URL oracle = new URL(weburl);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.contains("EUR</b>"))
                {
                    String command = line.split("EUR</b>").toString();
                    final String value = command.substring(8);
                    final StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer(value, " ");
                    final String DurationString = s.nextToken();                

                    System.out.println("Timh: " + DurationString);
                }
            }
            in.close();
```

this does not work for me until now.
How should i change it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) for this.

Note that eBay offers various APIs that will suit for your purposes.

https://go.developer.ebay.com/

Comment: what this has to do with what i asked :P? i just want leech prices from website :P into an array

Comment: oh i got it somehow but is weird.. i wanted do it with token e.t.c